# How to break a table with CSS diagonally or vertically?

Tags: html, css, html-table

If you have a `<table>` that is either very tall or very wide, and you wish to have it wrap to display on a screen. How can this be done with CSS?

Example: A table that is 300% page height and 30% page width would be broken into three parts.

```
#
#
#
#
#
#
```

to

```
# # #
# # #
```

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution, is this possible?

Edit: HTML Sample

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Bar</th>
            <th>Baz</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>34</td>
        </tr>
        [snip 100 lines]
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Annan: If you define the height of the <tbody> you will have a scrollable table with the <thead> and <tfoot> fixed but the rows will be scrooable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to:

```
tr {
    border: 1px dashed #f0f;
    float: left
}
```

That will work in IE8+ and all modern browsers. It fails in IE7.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/XeLUV/
or with a `width`: http://jsfiddle.net/XeLUV/1/

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done using a table. You'll need to split the table into three separate tables and re-format the page from there.

CSS does provide a `columns` feature, which allows the content in block elements to be displayed in columns (ie like newspaper columns), but this won't work with table content, and in any case it also has limited browser support (not supported in IE9; vendor prefixes elsewhere), so probably not recommended for mainstream use yet.

But if you do want to find out more about it, Quirksmode has a good write up on how to use this feature: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

And you can see the current browser support situation at CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#search=columns